# re.split on multiple characters (and maintaining the characters) produces a list containing also empty strings

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I need to split a mathematical expression based on the delimiters. The delimiters are `(`, `)`, `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `^` and space. I came up with the following regular expression

```
"([\\s\\(\\)\\-\\+\\*/\\^])"
```

which also keeps the delimiters in the resulting list (which is what I want), but it also produces empty strings `""` elements, which I don't want. I hardly ever use regular expression (unfortunately), so I am not sure if it is possible to avoid this.

Here's an example of the problem:

```
>>> import re
>>> e = "((12*x^3+4   * 3)*3)"
>>> re.split("([\\s\\(\\)\\-\\+\\*/\\^])", e)
['', '(', '', '(', '12', '*', 'x', '^', '3', '+', '4', 
' ', '', ' ', '', ' ', '', '*', '', ' ', '3', ')', '', '*', '3', ')', '']
```

Is there a way to not produce those empty strings, maybe by modifying my regular expression? Of course I can remove them using for example filter, but the idea would be not to produce them at all.

**Edit**

I would also need to not include spaces. If you can help also in that matter, it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `\w+`, remove the \s and do a findall:

```
import re
e = "((12*x^3+44   * 3)*3)"
print  re.findall("(\w+|[()\-+*/^])", e)
```

Output:

```
['(', '(', '12', '*', 'x', '^', '3', '+', '44', '*', '3', ')', '*', '3', ')']
```

Depending on what you want you can change the regex:

```
e = "((12a*x^3+44   * 3)*3)"

print re.findall("(\d+|[a-z()\-+*/^])", e)
print re.findall("(\w+|[()\-+*/^])", e)
```

The first considers `12a` to be two strings the latter one:

```
['(', '(', '12', 'a', '*', 'x', '^', '3', '+', '44', '*', '3', ')', '*', '3', ')']
['(', '(', '12a', '*', 'x', '^', '3', '+', '44', '*', '3', ')', '*', '3', ')']
```

Comment: Nice, this is exactly what I wanted to obtain! So, let me try to understand what you regular expression is saying. We have two groups of characters, one contains the operands (and parenthesis) and the other contains digits and/or words, right? The `+` after the first group signifies it can match a digit or a word with more than one symbol. But it would also match `12a`, right?

Comment: @nbro, yes, it depends what your input is going to be like,  i this a learning exercise or something else?

Comment: Well, I would like to parse expressions of this kind, but  I have had almost no practice with regex (as I am saying in the question).. Indeed, apparently doing `[\w\d]+` and `\w+` produces the same output, it seems that `w` matches also digits...

Comment: @nbro, I meant to use `[a-z]` not \w, I added a different method that will behave differently  with your `12a` example

Comment: Thanks!  By showing me different options it also helped me a lot in understanding better how regex work!

Comment: By the way, just a curiosity, if you know, why was my regex producing the empty strings?

Comment: Hei man, I think that at the end the "right" regular expression for my case would be `"(\d+|[a-zA-Z]+|[()-+*/^])"`, because I would like to capture also the cases when we have `a12B` (which becomes `a`, 12 and `B`) or `as12` (which becomes `as` and 12) or `asDA`. You don't need to modify  your answer, it nice to see different options and understand why they work and produce what they produce. I didn't know we could also not escape special characters within `[...]`, thanks for sharing!

Comment: @nbro, no worries, I tidying up  regex there, all you need to escape is the - in the character set as it has special meaning. Yep, you could also use `re.I` `re.findall(r"(\d+|[a-z()\-+*/^])", e,re.I)` a case insensetive match

Answer (score -1):

Just strip/filter them out in a comprehension.

```
result = [item for item in re.split("([\\s\\(\\)\\-\\+\\*/\\^])", e) if item.strip()]
```

Comment: I didn't downvote. I just wanted to do it using a regular expression, but if I really didn't manage to do it that way, then I would take a similar path to what you are suggesting...